# Elixir with "scp" -- permission denied and connection lost

Tags: linux, permissions, elixir, scp

I'm trying to copy a file from a remote server B to a remote server A. My Elixir application is on server A. I'm doing this:

```
a1 = System.cmd("scp", ["[serverB.....]", "/opt/folder1/"])  
# => Permission denied 
# {"", 1}



a2 = System.cmd("scp", ["serverB.....]", "/home/my_user"])
# => Connection to serverB closed by remote host.
# lost connection
# {"", 1}
```

In the 1st case I receive nothing but Permission Denied.

In the 2nd case I do receive a file, that's good, but why does it look like it's failed?

**My goal** is to get the **first** to work because I want file to be downloaded directly to "/opt/folder1/". Preferably.

How can I do that? Is it possible via scp? Or should I download it to my home directory first?

And why does it kind of fail in the **2nd case**, what's wrong?

Also, maybe I should instead use `rsync` to avoid the permission issues?

**update:**

I've given the permissions to the folder "/opt/folder1/"

```
  sudo chmod 775
```

but the error hasn't gone away.

**update2**

I've given the permissions 777. It kinds of works -- the file is downloaded. But the return result is still this:

```
Connection to bb.bb.bb.bb closed by remote host.
lost connection
               {"", 1}
```

Why is that? 1 implies "error" doesn't it? Let alone  "lost connection".

Comment: What happens if you try the same command with the same user from the shell prompt?  This looks like it's an issue with `my_user` not having permission to write to `/opt/folder1/`

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, the same -- permis. denied. but how to cure that?

Comment: Are you the admin on the box?  If so, you need to figure out how to give `my_user` permissions.  If not, ask the administrator to help you out.  Either way this isn't really an Elixir question--its more of a question regarding scp and permissions in Linux.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, I mean, I'm able to use "sudo" with no password, but because I'm using "scp", is it possible to fix the issue with  'scp" with "sudo"?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci non-zero return value on unix systems _implies_ that the error occurred (by consideration, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to the `serverB` with plain old good `ssh` and execute:

```
sudo chown -R my_user /opt/folder1/
```

or (if and only you perfectly understand the consequences):

```
sudo chmod a+xw /opt/folder1/
```

Logout from remote. Now you should be able to execute `System.cmd/3` successfully.

In general, the format of the `scp` command would be:

```
scp SOURCE_FILE TARGET_USER@TARGET_HOST:TARGET_DIR
```

So you’d probably better execute:

```
System.cmd("scp", ["my_local_file", "my_user@bb.bb.bb.bb:/opt/folder1/"])
```

That way you should receive `{"", 0}` response from [`System.cmd/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/System.html#cmd/3).

Comment: I need to download file, not upload it.

Comment: 1. You might follow the link I provided to ensure youself it is /3. 2. Swap parameters then.

Comment: 1. я уже удалил 1) хахаха